# DVI-D connection does not display properly at higher resolutions (2560 x 1440)

Tags: dvi

I have two computers connected to a Dell U2711 monitor. A PC which is connected using DisplayPort and a Mac connected using DVI-D.

The PC displays 2560 x 1440 resolutions perfectly but when I try and set that resolution on the Mac it displays in an extremely fuzzy manner. So fuzzy in fact that I can hardly read the text on the screen.

I've tried the Mac out connected via DisplayPort (unfortunately the monitor only has one DisplayPort connection) and it worked perfectly. I also had it connected via DVI-D in the past and it worked then. For some reason it just does not work anymore.

I was wondering if this problem might be caused by a dodgy cable or perhaps not having the correct one.

Can anyone think of what the issue might be? I've checked out the DVI-D spec and it should be able to display resolutions of 2560 x 1440 correctly.

Comment: Do you use a dual-link DVI capable cable with a full 8x3 pin array?

Comment: Did you use the same cable as you used in the past? If not, was the old DVI cable dual link and us the new cable single link? (See http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:DVI_Connector_Types.svg&page=1 )

Comment: @Hennes Ah that was it. I feel like a fool now. I was trying to use a DVI-D single link cable rather than a double link cable. Thank you both for the help :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher resolutions and refresh rates require a Dual Link DVI cable.

- DVI-I includes analog signals so can be used with a DVI to VGA
  passive adapter.
- DVI-D is digital only and can't be used with a VGA passive adapter
- Single Link can't do higher resolutions and refresh rates.
- Dual Link can do higher resolutions and refresh rates.

[image]

Image from Wikipedia article: [Digital Visual Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface)